# Bayesian Belief Network

Tags: c#, bayesian-networks

In the Kevin Murphy's example of Bayesian Network the Infer.NET library is used.  Is the Infer.NET required?

Comment: Could you find a way to phrase this so it's not a "plz send teh code" question?

Answer (score 2):

If your question is "Is Infer.NET the only library for performing computations on Bayesian Networks?"  Then the answer is **no**, there are several.  A quick google search turns up a [list of Bayesian Network software](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Bayes/bnsoft.html).

Comment: From the link you provided, I see that, Infer.net is the only library available for C#. (The question is tagged with C#).

Comment: May be the person should also mention that in their query somewhere.. :P